# How to access Firebase data without using addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to access firebase data without having to use the addValueEventListener? This way, I can access the data whenever I need, as opposed to being restricted to access it only when there is a data change.

I am coding in Java. Thanks :)

Comment: A `ValueEventListener` will fire straight away for the initial data and then for every subsequent change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to get the value of a location in your database is one of the `getValue()` methods of [DataSnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).  The only way to get a `DataSnapshot` is as a parameter of a callback method of one of the listeners: [ValueEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) or [ChildEventListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener).

You can get the current value of a location one time using [Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query). The listener callback method, `onDataChange()`, will fire once with a `DataSnapshot` that provides the value of the data at the location. To get a callback for the current value and each subsequent change, use [Query.addValueEventListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html).  To get the current values and changes to the children of a location, use [Query.addChildEventListener()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Query).